# Изменить желтый бэкграунд у input при автозаполнении. Возможно ли?

Tags: html, css, input

*Реально ли изменить стили стандартного автокомплита браузера?*
Речь идет вот об этом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сначала задался вопросом, а как вообще убрать этот фон? И нашел весьма хитрое решение:
Например есть какой-то инпут и ему прописываем в css

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
        transition: all 5000s ease-in-out;
    }
```

Типо ставим очень длительную задержку, например 5000 секунд как здесь, и забываем об этом желтом фоне. Это единственное решение, которое я нашел, которое работает.
Либо задаем `<input autocomplete="off">` и вовсе избавляемся от автокомплита.

*Но отсюда появился еще один интересный вопрос. А возможно ли вообще управлять этим свойством?*

Например при автокомплите поставить автозаполнение синим цветом, или зеленым, или вообще картинку какую-нибудь поставить.
Обычные попытки по типу

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    background: blue;
    color: blue;
}
```

К сожалению не заканчиваются успехом(
И как же все-таки быть?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вы можете использовать псевдоселектор `-webkit-autofill`, чтобы настроить таргетинг на эти поля и стилизовать их по своему усмотрению. Стиль по умолчанию влияет только на цвет фона, но здесь применяется большинство других свойств, таких как граница и размер шрифта. Мы даже можем изменить цвет текста с помощью `-webkit-text-fill-color`, который включен в фрагмент ниже:

```css
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
textarea:-webkit-autofill,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:hover,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:focus,
select:-webkit-autofill,
select:-webkit-autofill:hover,
select:-webkit-autofill:focus {
  border: 1px solid green;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: green;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #000 inset;
  transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

```css
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
textarea:-webkit-autofill,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:hover,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:focus,
select:-webkit-autofill,
select:-webkit-autofill:hover,
select:-webkit-autofill:focus {
  border: 1px solid green;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: green;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #000 inset;
  transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
}

body {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-size: 2em;
  justify-content: center;
}

form {
  padding: 50px 0;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputFirst">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="exampleInputFirst">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputLast">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="exampleInputLast">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail">Email Address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" id="exampleInputEmail">
  </div>
 
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Так же, вы можете отключить совсем его: `<input name="q" type="text" autocomplete="off"/>`

Comment: Частично дублирует ваше решение, но в нем есть ответы на другие вопросы.

Comment: Супер. То, что и нужно было. Благодарю! :)

Comment: Балин. Принять ответ можно только через 2 минуты. Лимит голосов на сегодня исчерпан)) Через пару часов восстановится, обязательно поставлю голос, очень полезное решение!

Comment: @Dmitry_allread_return благодарю